# How to post the multi select value in controller?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a multiselect dropdown. I choose two values. But in my controller I got the last one only. I want to get the two then insert into the database as comma-separated.

**view**

```
  <select  name="Period_name[]" id="Period"  multiple="multiple" required>
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Period 1</option>
                <option value="2">Period 2</option>
                <option value="3">All</option>
```

**controller**

```
$Period_name=$this->input->post('Period_name'); 
print_r($Period_name);
```

Comment: try `$Period_name['tar']=$this->input->post('Period_name[]');`

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? seems to be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
$Period_name = $this->input->post('Period_name');
$comma_separated = implode(',', $Period_name);
```

Comment: print_r($comma_separated); results nothing

Comment: that means you are not posting correctly. Are you using an HTML `form` to submit your POST data?

Comment: print_r($period_name) resuls like  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )

Comment: yay.. no problem. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: u there..i have a doubt.can u help me

Comment: textfield? meaning input values? sum with JS?

Comment: do you have teamviewer? maybe i can help you remotely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104601/discussion-between-codegodie-and-rose).

Comment: plz give me a rply when u get time

Comment: hi im here. What do you need?

Comment: Yes i will be here later in 2 or 3 hours.

Comment: if any function available for clicking a button

Comment: @robins im glad to help, but you really should post a new question on StackOverflow. Once you do that let me know the link.

Comment: @robins im glad to help, but you really should post a new question on StackOverflow. Once you do that let me know the link

Answer (score 1):

Since you have edited your question then this will help you.

`$Period_name = implode(', ', $this->input->post('Period_name'));`

This will get the selected inputs and then separate them with commas.

Comment: How, have you tested it yet?

Comment: how to take this as comma seperated..?

Comment: I have added it to the answer